# Postgres equivalient in SQLite to search JSON object

Tags: json, sqlite, duktape

I have got the below Postgres Query:

```
db.queryAsync('SELECT _id, value FROM ' + store + ' WHERE (value->>$1)=$2;', [index, id]);
```

I want to write the same in SQLite. I have created the value field as TEXT type, but then not sure how to query. I am using SQLite and JavaScript running on Duktape.

Comment: I don't think SQLite has JSON query capabilities. If you always search on the same field (`"index"`) you probably want to denormalize that into a column so that it can be queried.

Comment: The JSON objects have different key values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/json1.html) extension of SQLite. Altough it is marked as "Draft" it should be quite stable.

The SQLite statement corresponding to your PostgreSQL example would be:

```
SELECT _id, value FROM store WHERE json_extract(value, '$.someField') = 'some value';
```